# How to embed URL inside text in html?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I have this simple code in an sql stored procedure:

```
Declare  @EmailBody varchar(MAX),
 @MyURL varchar(2000);
SET @MyURL ='www.google.com';

SET @EmailBody = 'Please go here: <a href="' + @MyURL + '">';
```

Now, the `EmailBody` contains: "*Please go here: www.google.com*".
Instead, I want the url (*www.google.com*) to be embedded inside the word **here**.

Comment: Aside from the invalid html, consider tranferring this functionality from your database to the application that sends the parameters.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your html is wrong.  Try this:

```
SET @EmailBody = 'Please go <a href="' + @MyURL + '">here</a>:';
```

Comment: It should also use `http://` or `https://` at the start of the url to designate the protocol to use.

Comment: I already solved it, sorry to post such easy stuff!But will acceot your answer!